# Read user's music library within Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm currently developing an app with Phoengap which uses peer-to-peer connection through WebRTC. For my purposes I need to list the sounds available on the user's device.
So I'd like to know if it's currently possible with Phonegap to gain access to the user's music library and e.g. list all available songs sorted by artists? I came across [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-audioplayer-with-phonegap-application-setup--mobile-16347) from Aurelio de Rosa but I tested it and it doesn't seem to work on iOS.
Any suggestions? Or is there maybe a plugin around which I'm not aware of?

Comment: Hey! Did you write/discover a plugin that could do this?

Comment: I recently came over http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-play-music-from-a-users-library-with-the-phonegap-file-api/ for Android and https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/ios-audio-picker for iOS but haven't tested them. Would be nice if you could share your experiences if you're going to test it.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Sure I will. I'm planning on making a start on something soon. So will come back soon with my thoughts :)

Comment: @mikejames any news on this?

Comment: hey, sadly not. The projects been set aside... @encyce12

Answer (score 1):

You can find the iOS SDK, Music Library Access example code [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-music-library-access--mobile-6188). I expect you will need to write a plugin to expose this to Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

Your link should work, but only with music that you store inside your app sandbox or inside the assets (inside www folder).

If you want to use the music library you will need a plugin

I have found one, but it's very old, you will need to update it. It searchs the music and plays it natively too
https://github.com/hutley/HelloPhoneGap1.0/tree/master/HelloPhoneGap1/Plugins/iPod

here you can find a tutorial about how to create a music player using Music Library Access, but it's in japanese. The code is in english http://blog.asial.co.jp/884